# How concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() would work if one thread has exit

Tags: python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to understand how `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()` would work. I have piece of code blow code. If it has exit in one of the thread, it's exiting near futures `for` loop and not moving further step.

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

_list = ['xy','z2' ,'a',' ']

def main(s):
    if 'a' in s:
        exit(0)
    print('Processed for', s)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as process: 
    futures = process.map(main,[elem.strip() for elem in _list if not elem.isspace()])

for r in futures:
    if r: print("Exception: %s", r)
print("Processed for all list.")
```

Execution output:

```
 % python3 test.py
Processed for xy
Processed for z2
```

Is due to one of thread exiting and we cant move forward with other stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call:

```
futures = process.map(main,[elem.strip() for elem in _list if not elem.isspace()])
```

You passing in the second argument to `process.map` a list of three values:

```
['xy', 'z2', 'a']
```

Your Future task only prints out a value if the input argument is not `a`:

```
def main(s):
    if "a" in s:
        exit(0)
    print("Processed for", s)
```

You only see `Processed for ...` messages for the first two items because when the argument is `a`, the method exits without printing anything.  If you were to rewrite it like this:

```
def main(s):
    print("Processed for", s)
    if "a" in s:
        exit(0)
```

Then you would see output for all of the items in the list:

```
Processed for xy
Processed for z2
Processed for a
```

---

> Sorry may be I couldn't convey my ask. Here what I’m missing is `for r in futures: ...`

The return value of `process.map(...)` is an *iterator* that will yield return values from your tasks. Since your `main` function doesn't return a value, the value of `r` inside the loop will always be `None`. If we were to rewrite your code like this so that `main` returns a value:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

_list = ['xy','z2' ,'a',' ']

def main(s):
    print('Processed for', s)
    if 'a' in s:
        exit(0)
    return s

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as process: 
    futures = process.map(main,[elem.strip() for elem in _list if not elem.isspace()])

for r in futures:
    if r: print("Exception: %s" % r)
print("Processed for all list.")
```

Then the output would be:

```
Processed for xy
Processed for z2
Processed for a
Exception: xy
Exception: z2
```

Of course, the label `Exception` is erroneous -- those aren't exceptions; those are just the return values from your `main` function. We don't see a return value for `main('a')` because in that case you call `exit`, rather than returning a value.

Comment: Sorry may be I couldn't convey my ask. Here what I’m missing is `for r in futures:
    if r: print("Exception: %s", r)
print("Processed for all list.") `

Comment: I've updated the answer to try to address that question.